# LED lights in series - only 2 out of 5 light

Tags: lighting, bathroom, led

I have just fit 5 MR16 LED lights in my bathroom as well as an LED driver. The lights are 4.5W and the driver supports 24W which is just enough (4.5 x 5 = 22.5)

When I turn them on, only 2 lights come on. Thought it was the bulbs so changed 3 with new ones. Now none turn on. I therefore took one out and now 2 turn on again. I'm thinking it's the driver not supplying enough power. Is this the right assumption?

Comment: yes 12v bulbs and 12v driver. I say in series because of the way they appear to be wired up (I didn't wire them up). From the junction box in the attic I have run the mains wire into the driver, then from the driver the wire goes to light 1, from here it goes to light 2 (centre light), from here the wire splits, one wire goes to light 3, whilst the other goes to light 4 and then 5.

Comment: "LED bulbs in series" has a specific meaning in electronics that isn't the case here.  

Can you test (only) one bulb at a time in every socket and make sure none of the positions/sockets are faulty?

Comment: I have just done this whilst waiting for your response and can confirm that all sockets work.

Comment: Is there any chance plugging them in backwards causes them to burn out?  What brand are the bulbs?

Comment: You might lack voltage to supply voltage drop reliably: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_circuit.  Std is 0.7 volts, but modern LEDs are all over the place, up past 3.5 volts.